# multiply every number in c() using R

Tags: r

How to use for loop to multiply every number in the given vector `L = c(2,5,8,9,...n)`?

Not quite sure how to multiply everything together..

```
L<-c(3,5,7,9)
for (n in L){
  print(n)
}
```

Comment: `prod(c(3,5,7,9))`?

Comment: `L` is a `vector`, not a `list`

Comment: do you mean multiply in a specific number, or multiplication of numbers together?

Comment: multiply all the numbers together. Would love to see what's happening in for loop.

Comment: @user10381476 i updated my answer

Answer (score -2):

Note that unlike some other languages, R makes a specific distinction between vectors and lists. Normally `c(2, 5, 8, 9)` as you've written produces a vector, which among other things, enables the use of `prod`:

```r
L <- c(2, 5, 8, 9)
prod(L)
#> [1] 720
```

Created on 2018-09-21 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: just complementing your answer, in R you should always use vectorization instead of a for loop.